# Не передается глобальная переменная в функцию класса с функцией

Tags: php, многопоточность

Столкнулся с проблемой выполнения функции в функции и все это классе библиотеки (*использую готовую библиотеку для работы потоков PHPThreads*).Я передаю ей в качестве аргумента глобальный массив с данными.Необходимо чтобы функция выполнялась в функции класса корректно.

Сам код:

```
<?php
    // error_reporting(E_ALL); - здесь ругается в основном на сессии 
    // $_SERVER['HTTP_PHPTHREADS'] = 0; - это только тормозит скрипт!
    include 'lib/Threads.php';
    $potok = 2;

    $mas = array(
        'id1',
        'id2',
        'id3',
        'id4',
    );

    function Eacher($m){
        foreach ($m as $value) {
            echo $value;
        }

    }

    $Thread->Create(function()  {
        Eacher($mas);
    });

    $Thread->Run();
?>
```

Comment: Вот README библиотеки, если кому-то поможет: (https://github.com/wielski/PHPThreads/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Что поможет? По нему ответ и дал вам. Какая у вас ошибка выходит при выполнении? Что в логах ошибок?

Comment: И попробуйте функцию `Id` объявить внутри создания потока.

Comment: @Visman Ошибки: Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_PHPTHREADS in /home/browserl/public_html/test/lib/Threads.php on line 12 Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /home/browserl/public_html/test/lib/Threads.php on line 67 Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/browserl/public_html/test/lib/Threads.php:12) in /home/browserl/public_html/test/lib/Threads.php on line

Comment: Первой строкой у себя в коде поставьте `$_SERVER['HTTP_PHPTHREADS'] = 0;`

Comment: @Maksym, а как вы запускаете этот код на выполнение?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Через браузер...

Comment: @Visman Ваш вариант с *$_SERVER['HTTP_PHPTHREADS'] = 0;* очень тормозит скрипт и результата никакого.Походу очень косячная библиотека,единственное обьяснение

Comment: К автору библиотеки обратитесь с вопросом.

Comment: И тормозит у вас код наверное потому, что работать стала библиотека. Лог ошибок смотрели после этого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем коде есть две проблемы:

1. Вы не инициализировали сессию. Похоже, что этот момент является критическим для работы используемой вами библиотеки.
2. Как уже сказал @Visman, вы неправильно передаете массив в новый тред. Вообще, в PHP для передачи значения в анонимные функции, нужно использовать замыкания. Однако, в вашем случае этот подход не годится, ведь выполнение задачи будет проходить в другом процессе. По этой же причине, вариант с глобальными переменными тоже вряд ли сработает. К счастью, используемая вами библиотека предоставляет специальные средства для передачи аргументов функции. Пример есть в  [readme](https://github.com/wielski/PHPThreads/blob/master/README.md#transfer-variables-to-the-thread).

Таким образом, ваш код должен иметь вид:

```
session_start();
include 'lib/Threads.php';

$mas = array(
    'id1',
    'id2',
    'id3',
    'id4',
);

function Eacher($m){
    foreach ($m as $value) {
        echo $value;
    }

}

$Thread->Create(function($vars)  {
    extract($vars);
    Eacher($mas);
}, array(
    'mas' => $mas,
));

$Thread->Run();
```

Comment: Чем теперь ваш ответ отличается от моего?

Comment: @Visman, наличием `session_start` (ну и текст вопроса несколько обновился с момента вашего ответа). Собственно, я в явном виде сослался на ваш ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы снова воспользовались моим ответом, чтобы ответить правильно.

Comment: @Visman, не ругайтесь =) Я сначала хотел дополнить ваш ответ, но посчитал, что проще будет и правильнее оформить новый ответ, чем редактировать ваш. Я просто сомневаюсь, что существенное изменение чужого ответа приветствуется на ru.so.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
require_once 'lib/Threads.php';
$i=0;
while ($i < 10) {
  $res = "lol$i";
  $mas[] = $res;
  $i++;
}
$arr = array_chunk($mas, 2);

function Id($m) 
{
  foreach ($m as $value){
    echo $value;
  }
}

$Thread->Create(function($vars)
                {
                  extract($vars);
                  Id($arr);
                }, 
                array(
                  'arr' => $arr,
                ));
$Thread->Run();
```

Answer (score -1):

Ещё можно так счастья попытать:

```
$Thread->Create(function(){
    global($arr);
    Id($arr); // возможно вот тут он ищет локальный массив $arr
});
```

Comment: Не туда, не сюда.И ваш и вариант @Visman не рабочий. Даже не знаю что и думать

Comment: @Maksym а что вы хотите вывести в теле функции класса? Сама функция Id() у вас выводит 5 массивов по 2 элемента. А так как вы используете echo, то массивы эти выводятся в виде строк Array.

Comment: Проблема в том что ничего не выводится. Пусто